# Concept polymorphism in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts

The short question is: how to make templated function behave differently, based 
on parameter concept support.

I mean, if type **T** implements some concept, then my function should process it specially, than other types, that doesn't.

The question extension is: how this function should be declared, so end-user can see  what types it supports in its declaration (user, shouldn't check the defintion in order to obtain this knowledge).

So that's my concrete example, I use the "concepts" idea as it's presented in "The C++ Programming Language" by B. Stroustrup, namely a constexpr predicates, instead of c++20's concepts, since my compiler doesn't support it, yet:

```
template<typename T>
bool constexpr is_matrix() { ... }

template<size_t N, size_t M, typename T>
class Matrix {
    ...
    template<typename U>
    Matrix& operator+=(const U& v) {
        if constexpr (is_matrix<U>()) {
            // handle matrix case
        } else {
            // handle scalar case
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

This example is taken from my simple Matrix/Vector lib, that I use to study software rendering. My idea here is to require type **U** to satisfy my concept (support all necessary operations, provide necessary type aliases) instead of requiring it being my Matrix type, when it fails that check it is supposed to be handled as scalar.

So what techniques, can be applied here in order to make this code clearer for end-user, and are there better ways to provide concept-based parametric polymorphism, than constexpr if?

My only solution to this problem, that I was able to come up with was usage of enable_if, like this:

```
    ...
template<typename U, typename = 
    enable_if_t<is_convertible_v<U, T> ||
        (is_matrix<U>() && is_convertible_v<matrix_value_type_t<U>, T>)>>
Matrix& operator+=(const U& v) {
    ...
```

Which is quite verbose and can't be called pretty, btw I would prefer to static assert that type should be either convertible or being matrix of convertible values instead of hiding this operator.

EDIT: On second thought about my solution, I actually could static_assert in the definition, but still providing assertion criteria in declaration

```
template<typename U, bool check = is_convertible_v<U, T> || (is_matrix<U>() && is_convertible_v<matrix_value_type_t<U>, T>)>
... {
    static_assert(check, "Type U should be either convertible to T, or being a matrix of convertible values");
}
```

EDIT2: Which further can be improved into more readable variant:

```
...
template <typename U, bool check = std::disjunction_v<
    compatible_type<This, U>,
    compatible_matrix<This, U>,
    compatible_vector<This, U>>>
Matrix& operator+=(const U& v) {
    assert_compatible<check>();
...
```

Comment: Are you planning to be rendering in arbitrary dimensions?  Software rendering typically only requires 3x3, 3x4 or 4x4 matrices.  If you try to abstract this into oblivion with templates and concepts, you are likely to end up with more bloated, less-understandable code.

Comment: Nope, I render 3D, so mostly 4x4 matrices, also my Vectors are actually aliases to a 3x1 and 4x1 Matrices. I used to know C++ when C++03 was a recent standart, so I am accomplish two tasks at the same time: learn a software rendering pipeline and features of modern C++

Comment: You're asking for so much pain!  Why not do yourself a favor and make a `Vector` class?

Comment: Nah, vector concept is enough for me :D I actually trying to get enough experience and comfort of "advanced templating" so I could later complete N-dimensional Matrix class from Stroustrup book with least possible (for me) code repetition :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply overload the operator for all types you want to support. You may also add another version that generates a comprehensible compile-time error

```
 Matrix& operator+=(Matrix const&);

 template<typename matrix, typename=enable_if_t<is_matrix<matrix>::value>>
 Matrix& operator+=(matrix const&);

 template<typename scalar, typename=enable_if_t<is_scalar<scalar>::value>>
 Matrix& operator+=(scalar);

 template<typename arg>
 Matrix& operator+=(arg&&)        // catch attempts to add wrong argument type
 {
     static_assert(is_matrix<arg>::value || is_scalar<arg>::value,
         "Matrix::operator+=(arg) requires matrix or scalar argument");
     assert(false);
     return*this;
 }
```

You may also declare the last operator `[[noreturn]]`.

Comment: What if I need also support vector concept? `is_vector<vector>`, overloading won't help me further, as I add more concepts to support and `(T const &)` signature would be already defined.

Comment: @kravitz you have make sure that the overloads don't overlap in what they accept. If they do, then you have a problem before you arrive at the C++ rules for overload resolution: what *should* it mean to "add" something if you can both "vector add" it and also "matrix add" it. That will likely involve compile time matrix sizes to disambiguate

Comment: Well, vector add in my terms is actually same to matrix add, but It doesn't matter whether it's transposed or not. It doesn't matter what concrete concept It is, I am wandering how can this solution be generalized on N (N>2) concepts